Building v8 and adding it to C++ projects
I followed this websites guide, together with a few old stackoverflow posts:
https://v8.dev/docs/source-code
Howerver, after the long compiling process, it seems like I am missing a lot of important .lib files which I would need to add to my c++ project in order for it to work with v8.
My v8/include folder looks fine, I have all the v8.h files that I need, but just the v8.lib is missing.
Inside the v8/out.gn/x64.release folder, I have the following lib files:

I've read, that I would need to include a "v8.lib" and/or "v8_libplatform.lib" to my linker, instead I only have a "d8.lib" which doesn't seem to do the job.
So now I wonder, what did I do wrong (as I followed the docs 1 by 1)?
What I researched so far:
I read that I could use is_component_build = true to compile it as shared libraries (.su files) instead, but I'm not sure how to use those .su files inside my c++ project and I'd rather have a .lib file which I can include.

All .lib files sizes are 2KB, and one has 3KB. They do not look like correct build results. You did smth wrongly. Follow the guide accurately.
